Monogame/Xamarin error with .net8 x86/x86_64 configs for Android <= 28
I am facing with a strong issues with my Monogame/Xamarin app.
Monogame is updated to 3.8(.1.303).
I migrated from .NET6 to .NET8, and finaly my app is ok.
Not completely to be honest, maybe someone knowsthe cause of this behaviour ?
I investigated again and again, so now I ask the community :)
I build on the 4 following targets for android 21 -> 34 :

arm32 & 64 --> no problem
x86 and x64 --> no problem with android >= 29
x86 and x64 crash for android <= 28.
(I used firebase to get lot of device/target test deployements)

The issue I am facing on during the execution :

game constructor is fully executed good
game Initialize -> loadContents --> the code is not reached.
So it is located at the start of the app.

To remind, in the native sequence of a monogame app, it is mainly :
Activity.OnCreate
Game Constructor
Game Initialize (Load contents)
And a master loop on the update() and draw() methods.
The crash is occring during the starting, and all I did is try catched, and I have no catched exceptions of course.
In //, to complete the desciption, the OnCreate(Bundle bundle) method is also fully executed without exceptions.
I looks like the process is killed after the Game class constructor.
The same code works perfectly for the other configs.
Maybe there is something deprecated... but I don't know.
If someone can help me, it will be the first great news from 2 weeks :)
Cheers !
